# Exclude Certain Year from a Date Column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using Oracle Database version 12.1.0.2.0. I'm running a query that returns two columns, "Permit #" and "Date Issued."

```
SELECT id.B1_ALT_ID AS "Permit #", process.REC_DATE AS "Date Issued"
FROM process
LEFT JOIN id ON ( id.B1_PER_ID1 = process.B1_PER_ID1 AND id.B1_PER_ID3 = process.B1_PER_ID3 )
WHERE id.B1_PER_ID1 like 'B2021%'
AND process.SD_APP_DES = 'Issued';
```

Sample result:

[image]

**Question:** How can I *exclude* records from the year **2022**?

I tried adding to my original query the following clause to exclude the year:

```
AND TO_CHAR( process.REC_DATE ) NOT LIKE '%2022%';
```

But I received the same result. How can I results that don't include 2022 in the "Date Issued" column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
WHERE process.rec_date <  DATE '2022-01-01'
OR    process.rec_date >= DATE '2023-01-01'
```

*(Note: this may use an index on the `date_issued` column. The options below would require a function-based index to use an index.)*

or

```sql
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM process.rec_date) != 2022
```

or

```sql
WHERE TO_CHAR(process.rec_date, 'YYYY') != '2022'
```

or

```sql
WHERE TRUNC(process.rec_date, 'YYYY') != DATE '2022-01-01'
```

Comment: Thank you, MT0. I tried all of the options and they all worked. 